# Why do I get two different inverse matrices for the same N * N matrix as N increases in Matlab?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, inversion

As an experiment I just wanted to see the computational times between Cayley-Hamilton theory and the MATLAB `inv()` function. I knew that C-H would be slower on a CPU due to the amount of matrix products, however I wasn't expecting them to give me different answers as N increases.

For square matrices less than around 30 * 30, the inverses are about the same. But after this point they begin to differ from each other quite drastically. By the time N = 100 they share no similarities at all.

Is this a numerical computation issue, or is there something else happening here? 
Also which can I trust? I'm assuming `inv()`is highly optimised and trust worthy, but it would be nice to have some input from others.

Here is the code:

```
n = 100;
A = randn(n);

% MATLAB inv()

tic;
initime = cputime;
time1   = clock;
A_inv = inv(A);
fintime = cputime;
elapsed = toc;
time2   = clock;
fprintf('TIC TOC: %g\n', elapsed);
fprintf('CPUTIME: %g\n', fintime - initime);
fprintf('CLOCK:   %g\n', etime(time2, time1));

% Cayley-Hamilton inversion

tic;
initime = cputime;
time1   = clock;
p_coeff = poly(A);
A_inv_2 = 0;
for ii = 1:n-1
    A_inv_2 = A^(ii)*p_coeff(end-1-ii) + A_inv_2;
end
A_inv_2 = 1/-p_coeff(end) * (A_inv_2 + eye(n)*p_coeff(end-1));    

fintime = cputime;
elapsed = toc;
time2   = clock;
fprintf('TIC TOC: %g\n', elapsed);
fprintf('CPUTIME: %g\n', fintime - initime);
fprintf('CLOCK:   %g\n', etime(time2, time1));
```

Thank you to anyone who takes the time to answer.

Comment: If I remember correctly, computing the characteristic polynomial in a numerically stable way is tricky. So I suspect that poly() is the one responsible. However, this is just a guess. I'm upvoting in the hopes that someone more knowledgeable than me answers this question.

Comment: I bet on numerical issues as the explanation. I remember Noble's and Daniel's _Applied Linear Algebra_ book always insisting that you should not implement your own inverse routies, because they are bound to suffer from numerical issues. There a lot of optimizations to be done to avoid those issues, and `inv` no doubt has those optimizations. As to which you can trust: `inv`, of course. Compare `imagesc(A*A_inv)` and `imagesc(A*A_inv_2)` in your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cayley-Hamilton method is a very unstable method for computing inverses because it involves raising matrices to high powers.

Consider a matrix that can be diagonalized into `A=inv(P)DP` where D is a diagonal matrix.  When raised to the 100th power, this becomes `A^100 = inv(P) D^100 P`.  Any difference in size between the diagonal entries in D will be blown up by this operation.  For example, consider the difference between 2^100 and 0.5^100.

It is actually easy to see this within your Matlab program.  Print out A * A_inv and A * A_inv_2.  The first is very close to the identity, while the second contains nonsense:

```
A*A_inv_2
ans = 1.0e10 *
  0.2278  0.3500 -0.2564 ...
```